# Preventing bots from running PHP scripts

Tags: php, bots

We have a directory that is open to the web where we place utility scripts, some of them used for submitting Email, others for calling generic functions on our web service.

In my PHP error log, I am constantly getting notices and warning that the data that is used in the script has an issue, like "undefined index" or "trying to get property of non-object".

Several of these script I **know** are not being used anymore, yet there are still entries in the log file from **someone** attempting to run those scripts.

What can I do to prevent this from happening in my legitimate scripts? They need to be avail to the web due to them being called via ajax from multiple pages.

**Update ---**
I figured out that the reason they were even able to be run by bots was that the directory didn't have protection from directory listings; meaning that the bots had read the listing and ran them from there without really knowing what they did.

I added the option to prevent directory listings to my .htaccess and I am going to monitor things to see if it helps.

*On another note to all those suggesting blocking via IP or password protect them...
After checking some log files, checking for IP will not work because the scripts are being called both from the server, in PHP scripts, AND via ajax from the client. Also, to protect with password means I'd have to modify every place that calls the scripts to pass that password.*

Hopefully my mods will help tremendously but it may not prevent bots that already know the scripts are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the option to prevent directory listings to my .htaccess.

This brought down the execution fo the scripts by bots down to almost zero. I can live with the number I'm receiving now.

Answer (score 0):

You could/should protecte those scripts with IP restrictions or logins. Both can be done with .htaccess files. This is probably enough for simple utility scripts. You should not use something like this for a complex and secure application though.

Sample .htaccess file:

```
# BAN USER BY IP
<Limit GET POST>
 order allow,deny
 allow from all
 deny from 1.2.3.4
</Limit>

# login
AuthName "Test"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile test/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

Sample .htpasswd file

```
test:Qh8a4zM4Z/i1c
```

There are even generators for these files.
Some sample that Google found: http://www.toshop.com/htaccess-generator.cfm

Comment: But wouldn't the code `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` show the USER'S IP instead of the IP of the server containing the ajax code? I have no way of knowing if it is a legitimate IP.

Comment: I dont understand your question. The .htaccess rule in the "deny from" clause above will refer to the IP of the client (if you arent behind some bad load balancer). No PHP involved here.

Comment: The issue here is how to determine legitimate user IP's which there is no way of doing so this technique won't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call PHP script directly, or make scripts that are directly callable. This is the end goal. Probably not something you can implement right now.

If you take an Object Oriented approach all your PHP files will contain just classes. This means that when you run a file nothing happens.

Only **1** file will be an actual script and that is your *entry point*.

---

You're getting these `undefined index` messages probably because you're not validating your input (or there is a bug).

It's common to see a script like:

```
if ($_GET["action"] === "edit") {
    // edit
} else if ($_GET["action"] === "delete") {
    // delete
}
```

You expect to call the script like: `action.php?action=edit` but what if you call it like: `action.php`? You will get `undefined index "action"`

Add input validation like:

```
if (isset($_GET["action"]) === false) {
    throw new Exception("Invalid input");
}
```

---

If a file is no longer used, delete it. If you don't want a file accessible from the web move it out of the webroot.

Comment: The legitimate scripts always pass correct data to the scripts. It is the bots that are passing invalid data to them and causing the exceptions.

Comment: You need to do input validation. If you don't specify what _valid_ input looks like you can't make a distinction between a legitimate request and an illegitimate one.

Comment: If my **legitimate** scripts are passing valid data, why would I have to validate it? Anything without valid data would be a bot.

Answer (score 0):

I run scripts via a cronjob and have them protected by a password I pass through the GET, like this:

```
$password = $_GET['password'];

if($password == "somethingcool") {

    //the rest of your code here.

}
```

Then I call my script like this: `script.php?password=somethingcool`. If the password is incorrect, the script isn't executed.

There's a downside to this though.. if it's called from a public page, make sure you use javascript variables to set the password, or the bot will simple follow the link in the source code.

PS: Make sure you filter $_GET['password'], this current example is not safe to use.

Comment: This is not a secure way to deal with administrator scripts. Any person (or sufficiently intelligent bot) could look in the JavaScript and retrieve the password. Do authorization based on a **secret**, not information that is _also_ sent to the client.

Comment: They all accept POSTs only and since the majority of them are called via ajax, I don't think it very secure to have a password in the passed data.

Comment: POST's will work as well. It's not very secure indeed, but the scripts are publicly available anyway and your goal was to keep (spam) bots away right? If the bots aren't too smart this will work fine.

Comment: An alternative would be to check for the IP/domain calling the script and allow only your own website.

Comment: As some of them are called via ajax, this won't work because the calling IP will be from the client.